# Ubuntu 22.04 not reading NTFS HDD

Tags: mount, hard-drive

I switched to 22.04 (fresh install on new computer that is not dual booting Windows) and realized 22.04 is not reading my two usb 4T NTFS HDDs, but 20.04 on my older computer (that is also not dual booting windows) is still reading and writing to them just fine.

Following other suggestions on Ask Ubuntu I turned off Windows 10 fast boot (on my windows computer that is not dual booting Linux). I checked both HDDs for errors using Windows 10 and there are none. I shut down Windows 10 with the drives plugged in. Then I plugged the drives into Ubuntu 22.04 and it won't read them. I rebooted Ubuntu 22.04 and it still won't read them. The error I get is identical for each drive. Here is one of them:

```
Unable to access "Primary Backup"
Error mounting /dev/sda1 at /media/kevin/Primary Backup: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error
```

Does anyone have any idea what the problem could be? Maybe there's some driver I need to specifically install in 22.04 I forgot I had installed on 20.04 to handle these drives?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have `ntfs-3g` package? See if you have it installed using:

```
sudo apt list --installed | grep ntfs
```

If it's not there, install it using:

```
sudo apt install ntfs-3g
```

Answer (score 1):

Run:

```
sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdb1
```

It may help you.